# bootstrap multiselect onSelectAll get current instance

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a bootstrap multiselect that that are initialized with a js loop. I want to use onSelectAll to write a function where I'll want to uncheck a certain option. That can easy be done but the problem is that I can't get the current instance. On onChange using this gives me this instance but on onSelectAll it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to help you better, please post your code. Thanks!

Comment: So basically I have added onSelectAll: function() and onChange: function(). When I do I console.log(this) in the onchange function I get the multiselect object, but when I do in the onSelectAll function I get the option and I need to get the multiselect object in the onSelectAll function.